# how to copy a folder and its contents to another folder using xcopy?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, file-transfer, xcopy

So I've been trying to copy a folder to another folder. But whatever I do, it only copies the file(s) inside the source folder.

I've looked at numerous examples like:

[ss64 example](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)

[microsoft example](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323007)

e.g.

C:\Windows\system32>xcopy D:\sourcefolder E:\destinationfolder /e /y

I've tried various xcopy parameters like /s /e /t or a combination of 3 parameters.

**The end result should be a folder called "sourcefolder" inside E:\destinationfolder.**

I guess in UNIX terms, it would be something like:

```
cp -R /sourcefolder /destinationfolder/
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? thanks a lot

Comment: Create the target folder first. Then copy to the new target folder.

Comment: I can do that but it seems tedious considering it can be done using a single command on UNIX. but thanks for the suggestion. I might just do that if there's no way do it with 1 command.